# NestJs Global HttpExceptionFilter not working properly

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hello I'm trying to create a RestFul application using NestJs and I'm trying to create a global exception filter.

Basically I have to 2 endpoints.

1. `/api/user/register`
2. `/api/auth/token`

Each endpoint throws a different exception but I can't seem to get it working. It doesn't go through my ExceptionFilter class. Did I miss something?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

AuthModule.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'AuthClient',
        schema: AuthClientSchema,
      }
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

UserModule.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'User',
        schema: UserSchema,
      }
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule { }
```

AppModule.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Controller.ts

```
export class UserController {
  @Post('register')
  public register(@Body() registerDto: RegisterDto, @Res() res: Response): void {
     return this.userService.create(registerDto);
  }
}

export class AuthController {
  @Post('auth')
  public createToken(@Body() authDto: AuthDto, @Res() res: Response): void {
    this.authService.findByUsername(authDto).then((data) => {
     .....
    })
  }
}
```

Providers.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  async findByUsername(authDto: AuthDto) {
    throw new HttpException('Opps something went wrong', 500);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  async create(registerDto: RegisterDto) {
    throw new HttpException('Unable to create', 500);
  }
}
```

HttpExceptionFilter.ts

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost): void {

    console.log('<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', exception)
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Repo:** [click here](https://github.com/blitzen12/nestjs-sample)

Comment: can you provide repo?

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz repo added.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just in case someone encounters this. The answer is already in the their docs.

> Global-scoped filters are used across the whole application, for every controller and every route handler.

The solution is to catch the exception in `Controller` by either `Observable` or `Promise`.

**dumb me.**

Comment: I dont think it works that way either

Answer (score 3):

In order to catch **every unhandled exception** (regardless of the exception type), leave the     `@Catch(HttpException)` decorator's parameter empty

```
@Catch()
```

[Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything)

Answer (score 1):

According to [their docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#inheritance) there are two ways of injecting global exception filters. You can also try the second method, as presented below for your case:

`main.ts`

```
    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

      + const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
      + app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(httpAdapter));

      app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
      await app.listen(3000);
    }

    bootstrap();
```

Comment: I already tried that approach but still the same and I think already found out why.